# How to get Section box's current vertices after its translation

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

What I am trying to do is getting the exact position and its updated vertices of section box when we move it using gizmo. The above line of code is giving me min and max of section box and I tried to add mesh on it. Unfortunately, it is looking like this.

[section box which Autodesk forge viewer returns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Powpa.jpg)

[image]

created mesh using above section box values

After moving gizmo of the section box, it is giving me the same section box values. What I want is its updated corners or vertices after moving it from its original position.

I am attaching the code which I used to create section box's mesh using its bb values for cross-checking.

```
  const sb = this.viewer.getExtension('Autodesk.Section');
  var sectionTool = sb.tool.getSectionBoxValues();

  var sectionbbox = sectionTool.sectionBox;
  const sectionbboxmin = new THREE.Vector3(sectionbbox[0], sectionbbox[1], sectionbbox[3]);      
  const sectionbboxmax = new THREE.Vector3(sectionbbox[4], sectionbbox[5], sectionbbox[6]);

  const sbv1 = new THREE.Vector3(sectionbbox[0], sectionbbox[1], sectionbbox[3]);
  const sbv2 = new THREE.Vector3(sectionbbox[0], sectionbbox[1], sectionbbox[6]);
  const sbv3 = new THREE.Vector3(sectionbbox[0], sectionbbox[5], sectionbbox[6]);
  const sbv4 = new THREE.Vector3(sectionbbox[0], sectionbbox[5], sectionbbox[3]);
  const sbv5 = new THREE.Vector3(sectionbbox[4], sectionbbox[1], sectionbbox[3]);
  const sbv6 = new THREE.Vector3(sectionbbox[4], sectionbbox[1], sectionbbox[6]);
  const sbv7 = new THREE.Vector3(sectionbbox[4], sectionbbox[5], sectionbbox[6]);
  const sbv8 = new THREE.Vector3(sectionbbox[4], sectionbbox[5], sectionbbox[3]);

  var geometry = new THREE.Geometry()

  geometry.vertices = vertices

  geometry.faces = [
    new THREE.Face3(2,1,0),
    new THREE.Face3(0,3,2),
    new THREE.Face3(0,4,7),
    new THREE.Face3(7,3,0),
    new THREE.Face3(2,1,0),
    new THREE.Face3(0,3,2),
    new THREE.Face3(0,1,5),
    new THREE.Face3(5,4,0),
    new THREE.Face3(2,1,0),
    new THREE.Face3(0,3,2),
    new THREE.Face3(1,2,6),
    new THREE.Face3(6,5,1),
    new THREE.Face3(2,1,0),
    new THREE.Face3(0,3,2),
    new THREE.Face3(2,3,7),
    new THREE.Face3(7,6,2),
    new THREE.Face3(2,1,0),
    new THREE.Face3(0,3,2),
    new THREE.Face3(4,5,6),
    new THREE.Face3(6,7,4)
  ]

  const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
  this.viewer.impl.scene.add(mesh)
```

Is there any way to get Section box's current vertices after its translation.

attached code

Comment: Checking Engineering to find a workaround and will get back soon...

Comment: @BryanHuang Thank you. It will be great if I could get the answer very soon. I have deadlines for this task.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72742975/7745569

Here is the code snippet and snapshot.

[image]

```js
const cutPlanes = this.viewer.getCutPlanes();

if (cutPlanes.length <= 6) return;

let planes = cutPlanes.map(p => new THREE.Plane().setComponents(p.x, p.y, p.z, p.w))
let frustum = new THREE.Frustum(
    planes[3],
    planes[1],
    planes[0],
    planes[4],
    planes[5],
    planes[2]
);

let pts = this.getCorners(frustum);
let box = new BoxMeshHelper(new THREE.Box3().setFromPoints(pts));

this.viewer.overlays.addMesh(box, this.overlayName);


/**
 * Takes two planes and returns a Line3 which represents their intersection
 * use len to specify how long the line should be
 * @param {THREE.Plane} pl1 
 * @param {THREE.Plane} pl2 
 * @param {*} len How long the line should be
 * @returns {THREE.Line3} Intersection Line
 * // ref: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/is-it-possible-to-create-a-three-box3-from-a-three-fustum/6568/4
 */
intersectPlanes(pl1, pl2, len = 100000) {
    let EXTENSION = 2000000;

    let cp1 = pl1.normal.clone();
    cp1.normalize();
    cp1.negate();
    cp1.multiplyScalar(pl1.constant);

    let cp2 = pl2.normal.clone();
    cp2.normalize();
    cp2.negate();
    cp2.multiplyScalar(pl2.constant);

    // calculate cross product to derive direction of intersection line
    let crPl1 = pl1.normal.clone();
    let crPl2 = pl2.normal.clone();
    let cr = crPl1.cross(crPl2);
    cr.normalize();

    let dtPl1 = pl1.normal.clone();
    let dtPl2 = pl2.normal.clone();
    let dot = dtPl1.dot(dtPl2);
    let ang = Math.acos(dot) * (180 / Math.PI);
    // return null if planes are identical or parallel
    if (ang == 0 || ang == 180) return null;
    // project point directly if planes are perpendicular
    if (ang == 90 || ang == 270) {
        let intPt = new THREE.Vector3();
        pl2.projectPoint(cp1, intPt);
        let intA = intPt.clone();
        let intB = intPt.clone();
        intA.addScaledVector(cr, len / 2);
        intB.addScaledVector(cr, -len / 2);

        let intLn = new THREE.Line3(intA, intB);
        return intLn;
    }

    // project origin of first plane on to second plane
    let projLnAStart = new THREE.Vector3(cp1.x, cp1.y, cp1.z).normalize();
    projLnAStart.multiplyScalar(EXTENSION);
    let projLnAEnd = new THREE.Vector3(-projLnAStart.x, -projLnAStart.y, -projLnAStart.z);
    let int1 = new THREE.Vector3();
    let projLnA = new THREE.Line3(projLnAStart, projLnAEnd);
    pl2.intersectLine(projLnA, int1);

    // project the intersection point back to first plane along the second plane
    let projVcB = new THREE.Vector3();
    projVcB.subVectors(int1, cp2).normalize();
    projVcB.multiplyScalar(EXTENSION);
    let projLnBStart = cp2.clone();
    projLnBStart.add(projVcB);
    let projLnBEnd = cp2.clone();
    projLnBEnd.add(projVcB.negate());
    let int2 = new THREE.Vector3();
    let projLnB = new THREE.Line3(projLnBStart, projLnBEnd);
    pl1.intersectLine(projLnB, int2);

    // use cross vector and intersecttion point to create line
    let intA = int2.clone();
    let intB = int2.clone();
    intA.addScaledVector(cr, len / 2);
    intB.addScaledVector(cr, -len / 2);

    let intLn = new THREE.Line3(intA, intB);
    return intLn;

}

/**
 * Get intersected points of section box planes
 * @param {THREE.Frustum} frustum 
 * @returns {THREE.Vector3[]} Intersected points of section box planes
 * // ref: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/is-it-possible-to-create-a-three-box3-from-a-three-fustum/6568/4
 */
getCorners(frustum) {
    let lnLT = this.intersectPlanes(frustum.planes[0], frustum.planes[1]);
    let lnRT = this.intersectPlanes(frustum.planes[1], frustum.planes[2]);
    let lnRB = this.intersectPlanes(frustum.planes[2], frustum.planes[3]);
    let lnLB = this.intersectPlanes(frustum.planes[3], frustum.planes[0]);

    let int;

    int = new THREE.Vector3();
    frustum.planes[4].intersectLine(lnLT, int);
    let ptLTN = int.clone();
    int = new THREE.Vector3();
    frustum.planes[5].intersectLine(lnLT, int);
    let ptLTF = int.clone();

    int = new THREE.Vector3();
    frustum.planes[4].intersectLine(lnRT, int);
    let ptRTN = int.clone();
    int = new THREE.Vector3();
    frustum.planes[5].intersectLine(lnRT, int);
    let ptRTF = int.clone();

    int = new THREE.Vector3();
    frustum.planes[4].intersectLine(lnLB, int);
    let ptLBN = int.clone();
    int = new THREE.Vector3();
    frustum.planes[5].intersectLine(lnLB, int);
    let ptLBF = int.clone();

    int = new THREE.Vector3();
    frustum.planes[4].intersectLine(lnRB, int);
    let ptRBN = int.clone();
    int = new THREE.Vector3();
    frustum.planes[5].intersectLine(lnRB, int);
    let ptRBF = int.clone();

    let pts = [ptLTN, ptLTF, ptRTN, ptRTF, ptLBN, ptLBF, ptRBN, ptRBF];

    return pts;
}
```