# ForgeViewer get bounding box for a section

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have been struggling to find the bounding box for a section made using Autodesk.Section extension.

A [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56738766/how-to-get-bounding-box-info-of-intersection-box-in-forge-viewer) on this subject suggests that we use following functions to extract the bounding box.

```
const sb = viewer.getExtension('Autodesk.Section')
sb.tool.getSectionBoxValues() OR
sb.tool.utilities.getBoundingBox()
```

However, this value works ONLY for the default section box that appears when Section > Add Box tool is clicked. It doesn't update the bounding box when section box is moved to another location (or resized).

Is there a mechanism to correctly extract the bounding box?

I have also tried to compute bounding box using CutPlanes array as follows.

```
            const boundingBox = new THREE.Box3(new THREE.Vector3(cp[0].x * cp[0].w, cp[1].y * cp[1].w, cp[2].z * cp[2].w), 
            new THREE.Vector3(cp[3].x * cp[3].w, cp[4].y * cp[4].w, cp[5].z * cp[5].w))
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't give me the correct value either.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks,
Bandu

Comment: I'm checking with our engineering team, and will get back here A.S.A.P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, according to our engineering team, the values of `getSectionBoxValues()` won't be updated as expected. If you want to get the final values of the planes, you can call `viewer.getCutPlanes()` instead.

Here is the code snippet demonstrating this idea.

[image]

```js
const cutPlanes = this.viewer.getCutPlanes();

if (cutPlanes.length <= 6) return;

let planes = cutPlanes.map(p => new THREE.Plane().setComponents(p.x, p.y, p.z, p.w))
let frustum = new THREE.Frustum(
    planes[3],
    planes[1],
    planes[0],
    planes[4],
    planes[5],
    planes[2]
);

let pts = this.getCorners(frustum);
let box = new BoxMeshHelper(new THREE.Box3().setFromPoints(pts));

this.viewer.overlays.addMesh(box, this.overlayName);


/**
 * Takes two planes and returns a Line3 which represents their intersection
 * use len to specify how long the line should be
 * @param {THREE.Plane} pl1 
 * @param {THREE.Plane} pl2 
 * @param {*} len How long the line should be
 * @returns {THREE.Line3} Intersection Line
 * // ref: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/is-it-possible-to-create-a-three-box3-from-a-three-fustum/6568/4
 */
intersectPlanes(pl1, pl2, len = 100000) {
    let EXTENSION = 2000000;

    let cp1 = pl1.normal.clone();
    cp1.normalize();
    cp1.negate();
    cp1.multiplyScalar(pl1.constant);

    let cp2 = pl2.normal.clone();
    cp2.normalize();
    cp2.negate();
    cp2.multiplyScalar(pl2.constant);

    // calculate cross product to derive direction of intersection line
    let crPl1 = pl1.normal.clone();
    let crPl2 = pl2.normal.clone();
    let cr = crPl1.cross(crPl2);
    cr.normalize();

    let dtPl1 = pl1.normal.clone();
    let dtPl2 = pl2.normal.clone();
    let dot = dtPl1.dot(dtPl2);
    let ang = Math.acos(dot) * (180 / Math.PI);
    // return null if planes are identical or parallel
    if (ang == 0 || ang == 180) return null;
    // project point directly if planes are perpendicular
    if (ang == 90 || ang == 270) {
        let intPt = new THREE.Vector3();
        pl2.projectPoint(cp1, intPt);
        let intA = intPt.clone();
        let intB = intPt.clone();
        intA.addScaledVector(cr, len / 2);
        intB.addScaledVector(cr, -len / 2);

        let intLn = new THREE.Line3(intA, intB);
        return intLn;
    }

    // project origin of first plane on to second plane
    let projLnAStart = new THREE.Vector3(cp1.x, cp1.y, cp1.z).normalize();
    projLnAStart.multiplyScalar(EXTENSION);
    let projLnAEnd = new THREE.Vector3(-projLnAStart.x, -projLnAStart.y, -projLnAStart.z);
    let int1 = new THREE.Vector3();
    let projLnA = new THREE.Line3(projLnAStart, projLnAEnd);
    pl2.intersectLine(projLnA, int1);

    // project the intersection point back to first plane along the second plane
    let projVcB = new THREE.Vector3();
    projVcB.subVectors(int1, cp2).normalize();
    projVcB.multiplyScalar(EXTENSION);
    let projLnBStart = cp2.clone();
    projLnBStart.add(projVcB);
    let projLnBEnd = cp2.clone();
    projLnBEnd.add(projVcB.negate());
    let int2 = new THREE.Vector3();
    let projLnB = new THREE.Line3(projLnBStart, projLnBEnd);
    pl1.intersectLine(projLnB, int2);

    // use cross vector and intersecttion point to create line
    let intA = int2.clone();
    let intB = int2.clone();
    intA.addScaledVector(cr, len / 2);
    intB.addScaledVector(cr, -len / 2);

    let intLn = new THREE.Line3(intA, intB);
    return intLn;

}

/**
 * Get intersected points of section box planes
 * @param {THREE.Frustum} frustum 
 * @returns {THREE.Vector3[]} Intersected points of section box planes
 * // ref: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/is-it-possible-to-create-a-three-box3-from-a-three-fustum/6568/4
 */
getCorners(frustum) {
    let lnLT = this.intersectPlanes(frustum.planes[0], frustum.planes[1]);
    let lnRT = this.intersectPlanes(frustum.planes[1], frustum.planes[2]);
    let lnRB = this.intersectPlanes(frustum.planes[2], frustum.planes[3]);
    let lnLB = this.intersectPlanes(frustum.planes[3], frustum.planes[0]);

    let int;

    int = new THREE.Vector3();
    frustum.planes[4].intersectLine(lnLT, int);
    let ptLTN = int.clone();
    int = new THREE.Vector3();
    frustum.planes[5].intersectLine(lnLT, int);
    let ptLTF = int.clone();

    int = new THREE.Vector3();
    frustum.planes[4].intersectLine(lnRT, int);
    let ptRTN = int.clone();
    int = new THREE.Vector3();
    frustum.planes[5].intersectLine(lnRT, int);
    let ptRTF = int.clone();

    int = new THREE.Vector3();
    frustum.planes[4].intersectLine(lnLB, int);
    let ptLBN = int.clone();
    int = new THREE.Vector3();
    frustum.planes[5].intersectLine(lnLB, int);
    let ptLBF = int.clone();

    int = new THREE.Vector3();
    frustum.planes[4].intersectLine(lnRB, int);
    let ptRBN = int.clone();
    int = new THREE.Vector3();
    frustum.planes[5].intersectLine(lnRB, int);
    let ptRBF = int.clone();

    let pts = [ptLTN, ptLTF, ptRTN, ptRTF, ptLBN, ptLBF, ptRBN, ptRBF];

    return pts;
}
```

Full Code: https://gist.github.com/yiskang/d3c088f2633228a474301ce68f764c68

Demo Video: https://youtu.be/zqzyshGe3-8

Comment: Eason, Sorry for the late reply. I had to restructure my code to incorporate your solution but it really worked !!! 
Thank you very much.
Bandu